# In integer array the zero is not coming in values?

Tags: java, arrays

```
        int stdCodes[] = new int[2];
        System.out.println("Enter 2 STD codes:");
        for (int i = 0;  i <2; i++) 
        {
            stdCodes[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        for (int i = 0;  i <2; i++) 
        {
           System.out.println(stdCodes[i]);
        }



 Enter 2 STD codes:
    01975
    01887
   
    output:
    1975
    1887
```

While entering std codes in SDA i entered std code with zero but why zero is not in values at time of display array?

Comment: Because `int` data type does not support leading zeros as is your case. Use `String`s instead

Comment: Integers have the same value whether there is a zero in front or not.

Answer (score 0):

Since you declared the array as an int[], Java stores and outputs the result with just the most significant digits. You can store it as a string if you want to keep the 0, or format the output by concatenating "0" by hand before the stdCode

Answer (score 0):

The leading zero will be omitted when your input string is parsed into integer.
If you want to remain the leading zero you should choose the "String" data type.